# Visual Foxpro - Specific date subtracting two columns of numeric date and compare result

Tags: sql, date, numeric, visual-foxpro, subtraction

I am new to visual foxpro. I am trying to write the sql statements.

There are two columns of dates, data type is in numeric.

Column A date is in the YYYYMMDD format.
Column B date is in the YYYYMM format. DD is not available, thus I am only comparing the YYYYMM.

I need to subtract or find the difference between a specific date e.g. 31 August 2015 and the dates in column A and B. Once I have the difference, I need to compare and see if the difference in Column B is greater than Column A.

What I have thought is using substr and split the dates to YYYY and MM. Then I subtract it from the specific date, and then compare the YYYY portion to see if it column B is greater than column A.

Comment: If you actually have a choice, may I suggest you stay away from Visual FoxPro for any new development...  It is no longer a supported product: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=7992

Comment: What would the difference be between `20150831` and `201508`?

Answer (score 1):

Your description sounds as if `columnA / 100` would give a comparable format.

So if you've got test data like these

```
CREATE CURSOR test (columnA Num(8), columnB Num(6))
INSERT INTO test VALUES (20150802, 201508)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (20150712, 201506)
```

... you can get all rows where colmumnB equals converted(columnA):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE INT(columnA / 100) = columnB
```

... or get the difference between A and B for all rows:

```
SELECT INT(columnA/100) - columnB FROM test
```

Or if you've got a date-type parameter, you can for example get all rows where columnB would match the parameter:

```
d = DATE(2015,8,31)
SELECT * FROM test WHERE columnB = YEAR(d) * 100 + MONTH(d)
```

If you want to do something different, I'd suggest to edit the question and add more details